# What is the difference between apache tomcat deployer and core version?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

When seeking to install apache tomcat to set up a testing environment I encountered a serious dilemma.... apache gave me an extremely complex descision between two different versions of tomcat; they want me to chose between the core and the deployer version.

I would like to know what the exact difference is between the two.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The deployer is just an add-on tool to the Tomcat server; it doesn't contain the server itself.

So you need to download and install the core package.

Comment: But I want to use it in a development environment, so should I install both then?

Comment: The deployer is required in certain deployment scenarios in a production environment. You don't need it for development.

Answer (score 4):

*Core used for installing Tomcat on a machine and running apps on it*. *Deployer distribution contains only Tomcat Client Deployer - a package which can be used to validate, compile, compress to .WAR, and deploy web applications to Tomcat servers*.